# Templates in Ubuntu 22.04 not working

Tags: 22.04, nautilus, context-menu, templates

I frequently use right click -> New Document in Nautilus, or "Files". After a recent update, I am no longer able to create an option for this via:

```
$ touch ~/Templates/Empty\ Document
```

The command creates the file in ~/Templates/, but it won't show up in the context menu.

I've tried all permutations of these steps:

1. reboot
2. check if option exists in files
3. run touch command

I've also tried resetting Nautilus' settings with

```
$ dconf reset -f /org/gnome/nautilus/
```

Additionally, it may be worth noting that I've recently changed my system from auto-login to using a login screen upon boot. Other than that my install should be relatively clean other than installing and uninstalling chrome remote desktop. The issue only presented itself after the recent Ubuntu base (and other things) update

I would be curious to see if others can reproduce the issue. If not, a reinstall may solve my issue.

Comment: Check the output of the command `xdg-user-dir TEMPLATES` to ensure it's pointing to where you expect the Templates directory to be.

Comment: Thanks! That was it. I had previously taken a step to remove items from the left side of Nautilus. It involved changing my ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs file and thus Templates was pointing to the wrong location.

Comment: Good to hear 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! I had previously taken a step to remove items from the left side of Nautilus. It involved changing my ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs file and thus Templates was pointing to the wrong location.

Was able to determine the pointing location with

```
$ xdg-user-dir TEMPLATES
```